# Varnish caching too much files and not caching php

Tags: varnish

I'm using Varnish without touching any configuration (just the PORT forwarding to Apache to 8080).

But I got two issues:

- I visit a URL of an image, I delete the image, and I visit again and it exists … Varnish cached it … how can i tell varnish to look first if the file AT LEAST exists before serving it from his cache ?
- The PHP files are not being cached (I mean, the HTML content generated by the PHP). I always see in the Headers: Age: 0  … any clue ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

> I visit a URL of an image, I delete the image, and I visit again and
>   it exists … Varnish cached it … how can i tell varnish to look first
>   if the file AT LEAST exists before serving it from his cache ?

Eh, the whole purpose of caching is not having to do the same work (like checking for existence & loading a file, or generating a PHP response) over and over again, but to reuse the generated response. Varnish never new about the existence of some file to begin with (your backend server did the math) so it can never check if 'the file at least exists'.

There are however ways to instruct varnish not to cache urls forever. For instance; if your back-end response instructs any cache to not reuse the result (certain HTTP response headers indicate this), varnish will not cache it. Varnish will be smart enough (by default) to not cache responses with cookies too (which probably answers your second question). You can tell varnish to only cache a response for a certain period (like 30 seconds), so your deletes will be picked up pretty quickly. You could PURGE urls from varnish after you changed/delete a file. If your backend server does not tell this correctly with it's response headers, your can override this behavior by writing your own .vcl file.

> The PHP files are not being cached (I mean, the HTML content generated
>   by the PHP). I always see in the Headers: Age: 0 … any clue ?

I can guess: you're setting cookies. But it would really help if you added the response headers to your question.